# Does perl ftp class works?

Tags: perl, ftp

I have this simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Net::FTP;

$ftp = Net::FTP->new('apache.cs.utah.edu');
$ftp->login('anonymous', '-anonymous@') or die "login\n";
$ftp->cwd('/apache.org/httpd') or die "cwd\n";
$ftp->get('httpd-2.4.46.tar.gz', '/var/www/html/data/httpd-2.4.46.tar.gz') or die "get\n";
```

Now when executed, the output is `get` (which is message outputed by `die`). An error number return from bash is `110`, what kind of error happened?

Comment: Have you tried looking up the errors with Google?

Comment: The script works for me - as long as the target file is actually writable by the script. But if in doubt what is happening enable debugging in Net::FTP, i.e. `Net::FTP->new( ...., Debug => 1)` and include all the output you get from this in your question (by editing your question, not by posting as comment).